# Create object from a class. Save the object. Call the object from a third class

Tags: java, android

For this project, I'm using Android Studio. 
I've tried a bunch of things.

Goal:
I would like to create an application which asks the user to input data. The data needs to be saved and later be called on another screen as a log history which the user can see.

What I've done:
I have three classes: "InputScreen" "Logs" "LogHistoryScreen"

I've tried to create Logs object at InputScreen which works perfectly fine such as: Logs log1 = new Logs(); But I have no idea how to call the object log1 made in InputScreen from the LogHistoryScreen. Anyone who have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the concept of database storing if you want to store these logs in memory!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of logs in InputScreen class:

```
List<Log> logs = new ArrayList();
logs.add(log1);
// same for next logs.
```

then create a method in InputScreen which will return the list of logs. Something like this:

```
public List<Log> getAllLogs() {
  return logs;
}
```

Call this method from LogHistoryScreen like:

```
InputScreen inputScreen = new InputScreen();
List<Log> logs = inputScreen.getAllLogs();
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.
     
I got an error at logs.add(log1); It has a red underline and it says "In List cannot be applied".

This is the method in the class InputScreen:
public void buttonPressed(){
        Logs log1 = new Logs(150);
        List<Log> logs = new ArrayList();
        logs.add(log1);
    }

Comment: Please create list of your Logs type object specifically.

Comment: Ahh okay now I get it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are various options you could use here. I will mention a few here.

**1) Passing through Intent.**

Pass the Object as a parameter while you open the LogHistoryScreen from the InputScreen.

Please follow the below code to do so.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LogHistoryScreen.class);
intent.putExtra("Key", yourObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

Receive the Object in the onCreate() of the LogHistoryScreen activity

```
Log log = (Log)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Key");
```

The Log.class must implement Serializable.

```
public class Log implements Serializable
{
}
```

**2) Store the Object in the Database** and retrieve it from the other activity. This is particularly helpful if you need the data to persist across app sessions.

I think the first option will be more helpful for you.